# Design question - how atomic should a business layer method be?

Tags: c#, asp.net, business-logic

This issue is technology agnostic, but I am working with C# and ASP.NET and will use this for the pseudo code. Which is the better approach, and why?

1. Encapsulate logging, transaction and exception handling:

   ```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    SomeBusinessClass.SomeBusinessMethod();
   }


   public class SomeBusinessClass {
     public void SomeBusinessMethod() {
       using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope()) {
                   doStuff();
                   ts.Complete();
               }
               catch (Exception ex) {
                   LogError("An error occured while saving the order", ex);
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Delegate logging, transaction and exception handling to the caller:

   ```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
       using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope()) {
             try {
                   SomeBusinessClass.SomeBusinessMethod();
                   ts.Complete();
             }
             catch (Exception ex) {
                   LogError("An error occured while saving the order", ex);
             }
        }
   }


   public class SomeBusinessClass {
     public void SomeBusinessMethod() {
         doStuff();
       }
   }
   ```

I am concerned that by introducing dependencies on logging, transactions, etc in my business logic code, I make it less generic. On the other hand, the UI code looks so much cleaner. I can't make the call. Let me know what other factors I should consider.

Comment: I prefer Number 1. My reason is if the code has to be wrapped in a Transaction then the client who is going to call my code may or may not wrap it in a transaction. Also, the UI part looks much cleaner. I do have some way of letting the user know if something failed by not returning void.

Comment: Why do you use both using() and finally { Dispose() }??

Comment: queen3: great point, I fixed the example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Transactions**: a central concern of your business layer, so it should absolutely handle this (though you might centralize transaction handling via [a unit of work implementation](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html)).

*Update*: I don't agree with this part any more. Often, the controller, presenter, or or another top-level caller is the best place to handle transactions (a la the [the onion architecture](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/)) - in many cases, that's where the logical unit of work is defined.

**Exception Handling**: use as needed in every layer - but only use it in the business layer [when you can actually do something about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423358/asp-net-error-throwing-or-logging) (not just log it). Use a global handler in the UI layer if your infrastructure supports one.

**Logging**: use trace or informational logging in whatever layers need it, only log exceptions in the top layer.

Answer (score 2):

Use Inversion of Control:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 new SomeBusinessClass(_logger, _dbcontext, _exceptionhandler).SomeBusinessMethod();
}
```

A better one would be

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  _mybusinessclass.SomeBusinessMethod();
}
```

where _mybusiness class is passed to your page via IoC container, along with populated _logger, _dbcontext, and _exceptionhandler. If you need to create _exceptionhandler manually, for example "new RedirectExceptionHandler(this)", then

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  _mybusinessclass.SomeBusinessMethod(new RedirectExceptionHandler(this));
}
```

Now it really boils down to your specific design decisions. Don't know how to do IoC in ASP.NET, though, since I use MVC.

Another option is to use Aspect Oriented Programming to catch exceptions and do logging. Yet another option (available in www.sharparchitecture.net) is to handle transactions declaratively using [Transaction] attributes on method.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that makes the UI thinner will make your life easier.

Comment: Yup, yup.  As long as it's in one place instead of living in every place it's called; the rest is academic.